# can't understand this assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86-16

this code is supposed to calculate : p/4+v/8 using shift operations

```
Data Segment
Db p
Db v
Db q
Data ends
Code Segment
Assume cs:code,ds:data
Start: mov ax,p
       Shr ax,01
Mov cl,02
Shr ax,cl
Mov bx,ax
Mov ax,v
Shr ax,01
Mov cl,03
Shr ax,cl
Mov dx,q
add bx
Mov q,ax
Code ends
end
```

my main question is :
for me it seems like we're calculating p/8+v/16?!!!1
because i think there are 2 shift operations that are not needed

Comment: Yes you seem correct. Each `Shr reg,value` divides content of `reg` by `2^(value)`, and `q` at the end should contain the value you found instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That snippet of code calculates p/8 + v/16 as you said.

Every time you shift 1 bit to the right is like you were doing the integer division by 2.

So, you should remove the SHR ax,01 from both locations to get p/8 + v/16

Comment: Right. If you want to get p/4 + v/8 you should remove both SHR AX,01.